# Email notification to the requester

Tags: sharepoint-online

I made a SharePoint list with the following columns:
Service required,
Description,
Task status,
Requester :

I need SharePoint to send an email to the requester when the task status is changed to Completed.

SharePoint designer is not available, is their a way to use a formula

Thanks

Comment: Quick question: requester is a custom column or its a user who created the item?

Comment: Is it possible to use workflow?

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, Requester is the user who created the item, workflow is available but looks does not have all options when i tried to follow some posts answers